# Addressing python objects

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to use ncclient for Python.

If I do this it works:

```
from ncclient import manager
m = manager.connect()
```

If I do this it fails:

```
import ncclient
m = ncclient.manager.connect()
```

The error is `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'manager'`.

I don't understand what the difference is. Shouldn't that be the same method either way? Why isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Importing a module (package) does not automatically import submodule. (Some modules do. For example, importing `os` module also import `os.path`)

Replace following line:

```
import ncclient
```

with:

```
import ncclient.manager
```

to load the submodule `manager`.

Comment: Is there a way to tell (e.g., from pydoc) whether a submodule does or doesn't auto import?

Comment: You need to try or see the module's code (`ncclient/__init__.py` or `ncclient.py`) to see whether there's import statement for submodule.

Comment: @falsetru: It’s safe to assume only if it’s explicitly documented; otherwise a future version might, say, defer some imports to improve startup latency.

Comment: @DavisHerring That's why I suggested to use `import ncclient.manager` instead of `import ncclient`.

Comment: @falsetru: Of course: I’m just saying that “try[ing] or see[ing] the module’s code” is not really a valid way to find out whether importing a module implicitly imports another, since you shouldn’t rely on any implementation information obtained that way.

Comment: @DavisHerring, Ah, you meant comment. I commented that way because there was no documentation for `ncclient` module. If there was, I would link the documentation. Thank you for the feedback.