# When I import a package in my python script, does Python also import the sub package?

Tags: python, module, package

I am doing an online Python course and currently learning about modules and packages, but can't seem to get my head around the logic. I have used modules (or maybe they were packages who knows?) before in current job but without really knowing what was happening when I would do `import Pandas` for example.

By following the course I have created a folder called "MyMainPackage" and in this folder there is another folder called MySubPackage.

In "MyMainPackage":
**init**.py and my_main_script.py; in my_main_script.py there is a function called `main_func()`

in "MySubPackage":
**init**.py and my_sub_script.py; in my_sub_script.py there is a function called `sub_func()`

In Sublime Text editor I wrote a script called myprogram2.py:

```
import MyMainPackage
MyMainPackage.my_main_script.main_func()
```

However, this hasn't worked; when I call `python myprogram2.py` in Windows Command Prompt I get the following message

```
Attribute Error: module MyMainPackage has no attribute my_main_script
```

However, as per the online lecture, what does work is this:

```
from MyMainPackage import my_main_script
from MyMainPackage.MySubPackage import my_sub_script

my_main_script.main_func()
my_sub_script.sub_func()
```

Why can't I just import the entire package and access the modules like I have tried to above instead of the way the online lecture does it? I thought it would be the same thing. I am just struggling to understand the logic.

Comment: Are you sure you have at least an empty `__init__.py` in your `MyMainPackage` with two `_` before and after `init`?

Comment: @dmitryro yes, I do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Addressing python objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965201/addressing-python-objects)